# How to change View at revision editor in TortoiseHg?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I currently use **TortoiseHg version 3.0.2**

How to specify a custom editor for viewing at a specific revision?

[image]

Percisely, I would like to use SublimeText for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the file

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\mercurial.ini
```

and add :

```
[tortoisehg]
editor = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe" ["$FILE" -n$LINENUM] -multiInst -nosession
```

(this is when using notepad ++, for your case you have to put the path of sublime text